# Firebird-сервер жрёт много памяти

Tags: firebird, memory

Добрый день.

Прошу без ответов вида "погугли", уже гуглил, ничего полезного не нашел.  
Имеем Windows Server 2008, 64-разрядный. 8 гигов оперативки, 2 ядра по 3.5 Гц. На системе установлен Firebird 2.5 (х64) как SuperServer.  
Есть база данных. Размер почти 10 гигов, page size=16384. В течение рабочего дня около 70 пользователей подключены к базе. К концу дня процесс жрет 5-6 гигов оперативной памяти. В firebird.conf все настройки по умолчанию, кроме FileSystemCacheSize = 10. Но получается, что система не обращает внимания на эту настройку и потребляет всю память, что есть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать, что менять?

Comment: Может, у Вас висят длинные тяжелые запросы?

Comment: Запросы insert/update/delete все происходят в транзакциях, которые коммитятся или откатываются. Такие же не могут висеть? А запросы select могут?  И что именно подразумевается под "висят" и как это проверить?

Comment: как проверить - это я не знаю, с firebird работал очень мало. select как раз висеть и может. То есть, пользователь открыл выборку для просмотра и потихоньку тянет (например, прокручивая грид). Сервер БД вынужден держать данные по запросу.